# How would you assign a operator to a string in scheme? (ex: "A" == + , "S" == -, etc.) Im having trouble computing ("A" 1 2)

Tags: string, list, compare, scheme

Im having trouble computing ("A" 1 2)

Comment: You can't "assign" something to a string or any other kind of value. You can make a table that maps strings to functions, or a function that does the mapping. It's impossible to write `("A" 1 2)` and treat `"A"` as a function.

Comment: okay, that makes sense , what is an example of mapping a string to a function ?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to do this is with symbols, not strings:

```
> (define a +)
> (a 1 2)
3
> +
#<procedure:+>
> a
#<procedure:+>
```

Here symbol `a` gets bound to the same procedure that symbol `+` is (and remains) bound to, which means that both `+` and `a` can be used interchangeably.

If you need to use strings, you could use a procedure that, using a lookup table, converts a string into a procedure:

```
(define (s->p str)
  (cdr (assoc str (list (cons "A" +) (cons "S" -)))))
```

used like so:

```
> ((s->p "A") 1 2)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang racket
(define (combine sign)
  (cond ((equal? "A" sign) +)
        ((equal? "S" sign) -)))
((combine "A") 1 2)
```

also：

```
#lang racket
(define env
  (list (cons "a" +) (cons "m" -)))
(define (combine target env)
  (define (search env)
    (if (null? env)
        (begin (displayln "not found and the default operate is +") +)
        (if (equal? target (car (car env)))
            (cdr (car env))
            (search (cdr env)))))
  (search env))
((combine "2" env) 1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: yes that works , but Im wondering how to approach get that same result with in a list Ex: > '( "A" 1 2 )  3

Comment: `#\S` is a char, not a string, so it's different from `"S"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making your own interpreter then you'll have a sort of assoc list to map names to the actual implementation. Eg.

```
(define env `(("a" . ,+) ("m" . ,-) ("id" ,(lambda (x) x))))

(define (string->value sym env)
  (let ((v (assoc sym env)))
    (if v ; v is #f when not found
        (cdr v)
        (error "Variable not found"))))

((string->value "a" env) 4 5) ; ==> 9
```

It's actually more common to use symbols, but I can think of implementations where all values are strings.